# Rendering issue for Symfony forms ChoiceType for a new entity in a CollectionType

Tags: twig, symfony-forms, symfony5

In my web application I can create/edit/delete shifts in a shift schedule. These shifts are loaded as a table.
Now the problem is when creating a new shift (existing shifts don't have this issue) in my schedule, the dropdown is rendered incorrectly:

[First row is an existing shift and the second row shows how new shifts are rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we3oz.png)

My forms looks like this:

The shift schedule form:

```
$builder
            ->add('planningShifts', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ShiftFormType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'numberOfWeeks' => $options["data"]->getNumberOfWeeks(),
                ],
                'label' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ])
```

An individual shift in this schedule (ShiftFormType):

```
$weekChoices = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $options['numberOfWeeks']; $i++) {
            $weekChoices[$i] = $i;
        }

$builder
        ->add('weeks', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $weekChoices,
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,  //Note: When this value is false I don't have the render issue, but of course I need this to accept multiple options.
            ]);
```

My twig renders it like this:

```
<td class="cel-edit">
      {{ form_widget(shift.weeks) }}
   </td>`
```

I expect for new shifts that the dropdown will be loaded correctly.

Comment: Could you show the twig/JavaScript you use for adding new rows? In a CollectionType form new rows are usually added via JavaScript, so if the problem is only with the new rows, you might be doing something wrong there.